# No Bluetooth connection for keyboard and mouse for Dell XPS M2010

Tags: dell, bluetooth

I hope someone may be able to provide some assistance. I am running dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS

Comment: Does it work in Windows?

Answer (score 1):

you have to pair the keyboard to work on Ubuntu, but when you revert to windows 7 you have to repeat the procedure, I gave up trying, also I couldnt get sound through the speakers, only via mic.

Comment: I am pretty much new to ubuntu...would I install and run something like  Bluez? In order to pair the keyboard and mouse..is that correct?